# Rails: Calling JS function on form_for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a form_for with radio buttons, and I want to call a javascript function when the radio button is changed.

The radio buttons are for Chapter's field 'type', of type boolean.

```
<%= form_for([book.category, book, chapter], remote: true ) do |f| %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, true, onKeyUp: "alert('hi')", checked: 'checked' %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Link' %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, false, onKeyUp: "alert('hi')" %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Text' %>

<% end %>
```

I've tried onchange and onclick as well. I've tried adding a {} before the options, and I get an error from Rails that there are too many parameters.

Eventually I want to call a function that hides/shows other text fields, but I can't even get the alert to execute!

I'm sure this is something really simple, but I've been searching the internet for the answer to this for way too long. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this code actually works with an onclick event, inspect the generated HTML code with a developer extension like Firebug in your browser to make sure the attributes have been set correctly.

```
<%= form_for([book.category, book, chapter], remote: true ) do |f| %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, true, checked: 'checked', onClick: "alert('hi TRUE!');" %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Link' %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, false, onClick: "alert('hi False!');" %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Text' %>

<% end %>
```

---

Another way is to define a behavior using a data tag and then bind it with javascript (reference:  http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/10/data-behavior.html):

```
<%= form_for([book.category, book, chapter], remote: true ) do |f| %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, true, checked: 'checked', data: {behavior: "clickable"} %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Link' %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, false, data: {behavior: "clickable" } %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Text' %>

<% end %>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('input[type="radio"][data-behavior="clickable"]').click(function(evt) {
    alert("you chose the option: " + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

---

Let's extend this to your scenario for hiding/showing other stuff:

View ERB:

```
<%= form_for([book.category, book, chapter], remote: true ) do |f| %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, true, checked: 'checked', data: {behavior: "toggle-products"} %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Link' %>

    <%= f.radio_button :type, false, data: {behavior: "toggle-products" } %> 
    <%= f.label :type, 'Text' %>

<% end %>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"][data-behavior="toggle-products"]').click(function(evt) {
    if($(this).val() == "true") { 
      $('.products').show();
    } else {
      $('.products').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions but neither gives me the alert.

Comment: hey, I'm sorry there were some typos, I think I've fixed it now, please try again. Make sure you use a developer extension for your browser (like Firebug) and inspect the generated HTML code whether the onClick attribute has been set properly.

Comment: I've refactored and tested the first example, tested the second example too

Comment: Yay, it worked--thanks so much!! (I used the data-behavior one)

Comment: This is an old question, but I believe "click" is not an event of a radio input.  I would suggest using the *change* event by using the `onchange` attribute in place of `onClick` in the ruby code above